# Adobe Flash Media Server Admin Console

Tags: xml, adobe, flash-media-server

Today I install Adobe Media Server and Gateway on my linux server after installation finished I went to 'myipadress:1111' for the admin console but I only see

Mit dieser XML-Datei sind anscheinend keine Style-Informationen verknüpft. Nachfolgend wird die Baum-Ansicht des Dokuments angezeigt.
      error`NetConnection.Connect.Rejected`Admin user requires valid username and password.Fri Jul 12 13:21:30 2013

I know it's german but I hope you can help me I disabled the firewall and the ports are free dont know what else to be done

Answer (score 1):

Just enter the ip address without the 1111 it will bring up the adobe media server screen. There is a launch admin console link there. Hope this helps.

Comment: http://208.64.140.151:1111/ XML file
http://208.64.140.151/ : gives me apache index page